# Biopython Alignment using Muscle or ClustalW without file input

Tags: python, alignment, biopython, clustal

I'm actually building a script in python3 to calculate divergence between several paired sequences. So, I need firt to make an alignment between 2 proteines sequences and then make a codon alignment with 2 dna sequences. To make my first alignment (between 2 proteines sequences), I'm actually using

```
alns = pairwise2.align.globalds(prot1 ,prot2, matrix, gap_open, gap_extend)
```

But I need something more sofisticated such ClustalW or MUSCLE algorithmes. The problem is that my script is built in the way that I ask 4 sequences: 2 of dna and 2 of amino acides.

Then I convert my sequences in string. But ClustalW and MUSCLE ask to give a file with those sequences. Is there a way to give the sequences like that:

```
muscle_cline = MuscleCommandline(muscle_exe, prot1 , prot2, out=out_file)
instead of the input file (unaligned sequences file):
muscle_cline = MuscleCommandline(muscle_exe, input=in_file, out=out_file)
```

or like that:

```
clustalw_cline = ClustalwCommandline("clustalw2", prot1, prot2)
instead of that:
clustalw_cline = ClustalwCommandline("clustalw2", infile=in_file)
```

Because I do not want to creat a file with my sequence unaligned for each of my sequences (around 450)...

Thanks you very much.

Comment: I believe both ClustalW and MUSCLE are Bash scripts with python wrappers. You'll have to modify the wrapper code itself if you want to allow string input. I recommend writing files and immediately removing them after alignment using os.remove().

Comment: I think your questions might be better suited for https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions or at least use the `bioinformatics` tag if you post them here